# Javascript delete an object key array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this object:

```
object = {
   key:["1","2","3","4","5"],
   key2:["5","7","8","9"]
}
```

How do I delete an object key and how to delete an object key value ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For deleteing a property from an object you can use

```
delete object.key
```

For deleting an item from the array, you could use many methods, one of which is to make use of jQuery's `grep` method:

```
// removes "5" from the values
object.key2 = $.grep(object.key2,function(x) { return x != "5"});
```

Live examples: http://jsfiddle.net/rbREb/

Answer (score 6):

> How do I delete an object key and how to delete an object key value ?

Use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete) operator to remove a property from an `Object`.

```
delete object.key
```

Removing the property will remove its associated value (or at least mark it for garbage collection).

Comment: and what if i want to delete only the property value ?

Comment: @Ispuk You could assign to it `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: @Ispuk If you want to delete only its value, you could set it to null. e.g. `object.key = null`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use delete object[key]. This will delete both the key and value