# delete multiple object key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to remove multiple keys in object javascript.
how to remove the date keys in the obj.

```
var obj ={
  "id": "1",
  "cn": "TH",
  "curr": "THB",
  "10-02-2020": "10,11",
  "12-01-2019": "2,5"
}

var result = filterkeys(obj,["id","cn","curr"]);

function filterkeys(obj,arr){
   arr.forEach(function(key) {
    delete !obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "cn": "TH",
  "curr": "THB"
}
```

Comment: you can either try lodash `omit` or `pick` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript delete an object key array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320779/javascript-delete-an-object-key-array-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go the other way around - iterate over all keys of the object, and if it isn't in the `arr`, delete it:

```js
var obj ={
  "id": "1",
  "cn": "TH",
  "curr": "THB",
  "10-02-2020": "10,11",
  "12-01-2019": "2,5"
}

var result = filterkeys(obj,["id","cn","curr"]);

function filterkeys(obj,arr){
  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (!arr.includes(key)) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(result);
```

Or, without `delete` (probably better to avoid `delete` when possible - it's good to avoid mutation) - map the keys array to construct a new object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
var obj ={
  "id": "1",
  "cn": "TH",
  "curr": "THB",
  "10-02-2020": "10,11",
  "12-01-2019": "2,5"
};
const filterkeys = (obj,arr) => Object.fromEntries(
  arr.map(key => [key, obj[key]])
);

var result = filterkeys(obj,["id","cn","curr"]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign` and add the entries by required `keys` map.

Alternatively you can use `Reflect.deleteProperty` to remove unwanted keys.

```js
var obj = {
  id: "1",
  cn: "TH",
  curr: "THB",
  "10-02-2020": "10,11",
  "12-01-2019": "2,5"
};

const filterkeys = (obj, keys) =>
  Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(key => ({ [key]: obj[key] })));

var result = filterkeys(obj, ["id", "cn", "curr"]);

console.log(result);

const filterkeys2 = (obj, keys) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => !keys.includes(key) && Reflect.deleteProperty(obj, key))
  return obj;
};
var result2 = filterkeys2(obj,["id","cn","curr"]);
console.log(result2);
```